# Is there an Idiomatic phrase for "keep something near your hand/near you in range of your hands or eyes"?

Tags: phrase-request

In English is there a short/idomatic phrase to express that something should be kept in range of your hand or eyes?

I mean for example: *keep phone and email/something in hand range or eye range*

How can I express such range without using artificial-sounding language?

Answer (score 12):

I think a good choice would be the expression [*within reach*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/within+reach).

> I need to keep my phone within reach.

The expression is often used to say that something is close enough to be picked up right away. In the case of the phone, the phone is literally within reach (that is, within an arm's length, or maybe nearby in the same room). However, the expression can be used figuratively as well. For example, a university might advertise by saying something like:

> A better way of life is within reach.

meaning that, once you get a better education, there's a good chance your lifestyle will improve.

Comment: _A better way of life is within reach._ is really idiomatic since education context is hidden.

Comment: @Chameleon: Sure, that last example is VERY context dependent. A speaker could say those same words when, say, helping someone overcome an addiction, or trying to persuade someone to buy a house in a different neighborhood.

Comment: In Polish we say _a better life is in your range_ == _a better way of life is within reach_ or little more often in Polish _you have chance for a better life_ - probably it sounds strange in English :) Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: +1. This is definitely a good answer.  I'll just note that people sometimes use the variant *in reach* the same way, although *within reach* is more common.

Answer (score 11):

Another option would be *handy*:

> Keep your cell phone handy.

Per [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/handy), it means:

> 1:  a : conveniently near
>   b : convenient for use

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You can use the idiomatic phrase:

> I need to keep my phone **to hand**.

meaning that the phone must be kept somewhere where it is immediately accessible.

You can also use the idiomatic phrase:

> Can you **keep an eye on** the baby until I get back from the store.

In this case, the meaning is that the baby should be kept within eye-range until the speaker gets back from the store.

Comment: Can I say _You have to keep your phone and email access to hand_?

Comment: Hmmm... I would say [_"on hand"_](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+hand) or [_"at hand"_](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+hand) before I said _"to hand"_, but maybe that's a regional thing.

Comment: Another variation would be "near at hand" or "near to hand".

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, as a native English speaker, 'keep an eye on' would be the most natural phrase for this particular type of behavior.

> I need to keep an eye on my email and phone today as I'm expecting to hear from a hiring manager.

'Monitor' might be used as well: "I need to monitor my phone," but is not nearly as commonly used.

'Handy' and 'at hand' work well for a physical objects, but not so well for something more amorphous like 'email.'

'To hand' is one I've personally never heard before.

Comment: It's interesting how we can use "keep an eye on my phone," even when we mean we are listening more than we are watching.